# Estilos para la scrollbar con CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Tengo un problema al querer darle un estilo personalizado a la barra de desplazamiento.
mi codigo HTML donde esta el contenedor:

```
<div className="tareas-contenedor">
    <h2 className="title-tareas">Mis Tareas</h2>
    <ListaDeTareas />
  </div>
```

mi css:

```
.tareas-contenedor {
 min-height: 350px;
 max-height: 60vh;
 min-width: 600px;
 max-width: 750px;
 text-align: start;
 margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 25px;
 background: rgba(221,221,221,0.55);
 -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
 backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
 border: 1px solid rgba(221,221,221,0.275);
 overflow-x: auto;
 }
/* Barra de desplazamiento */
.tareas-contenedor::-webkit-scrollbar{
 width: 8px;
 background-color: #2546b8;
 border-radius: 20px;
 }
.tareas-contenedor::-webkit-scrollbar:window-inactive {
 display: none;
 }
.tareas-contenedor::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb  {
 background-color: #09C;
 border-radius: 6px;

 }
```

y el resultado es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
quisiera saber si hay una forma para que la barra no desborde el contenedor, ya que los extremos son mas grande que éste

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un `div` dentro de `tareas-contenedor`, encerrar a todo el contenido y mostrar el `scroll` únicamente ahí, así el `scroll` no se desbordará de `tareas-contenedor`.

---

Entonces, primero creamos el `div` adentro de `tareas-contenedor`, le llamaremos `contenido`, y este `div` encerrará a tu `h2` y a tu lista de tareas, quedando tu estructura HTML así:

```
<div class="tareas-contenedor">
  <div class="contenido">
    <h2 class="title-tareas">Mis Tareas</h2>
    <ListaDeTareas />
  </div>
</div>
```

Y a `contenido` le damos los mismos estilos (solo los necesarios) que tiene `tareas-contenedor`:

```
.contenido {
  min-height: 350px;
  max-height: 60vh;
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 750px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Y los estilos del `scroll` que se apliquen al nuevo `div` creado:

```
.contenido::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #2546b8;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.contenido::-webkit-scrollbar:window-inactive {
  display: none;
}
.contenido::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb  {
  background-color: #09C;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Y así el `scroll` se verá solo en `contenido`, y como `contenido` está dentro de `tareas-contenedor`, el `scroll` no se desbordará de `tareas-contenedor`.

---

Ejemplo:

```css
.tareas-contenedor {
  min-height: 350px;
  max-height: 60vh;
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 750px;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: rgba(221,221,221,0.55);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(221,221,221,0.275);
  overflow: hidden; /* oculto el scroll de este div porque no lo queremos visualizar */
}

.contenido {
  min-height: 350px;
  max-height: 60vh;
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 750px;
  overflow-x: auto; /* muestro el scroll de este div, porque es el que queremos visualizar */
}
/* Barra de desplazamiento */
.contenido::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #2546b8;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.contenido::-webkit-scrollbar:window-inactive {
  display: none;
}
.contenido::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb  {
  background-color: #09C;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tareas-contenedor">
  <div class="contenido">
    <h2 class="title-tareas">Mis Tareas</h2>    
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
    <p>texto de ejemplo</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con clip-path lo solucionas:

```css
clip-path: inset(0% 0% round 25px);
```

Donde los `25px` son los mismos que tu utilizas en tu `border-radius`

Demo:

```css
.tareas-contenedor {
clip-path: inset(0% 0% round 25px);
 min-height: 350px;
 max-height: 60vh;
 min-width: 600px;
 max-width: 750px;
 text-align: start;
 margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 25px;
 background: rgba(221,221,221,0.55);
 -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
 backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
 border: 1px solid rgba(221,221,221,0.275);
 overflow-x: auto;
 }
/* Barra de desplazamiento */
.tareas-contenedor::-webkit-scrollbar{
 width: 8px;
 background-color: #2546b8;
 border-radius: 20px;
 }

.tareas-contenedor::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb  {
 background-color: #09C;
 border-radius: 6px;

 }
```

```html
<div class="tareas-contenedor">
    <h2 class="title-tareas">Mis Tareas</h2>
    <script>
       for(let i=0;i<100;i++){
           document.write(`<p>texto de ejemplo</p>`)
       }
    </script>
  </div>
```